# Python3.5 Selenium2 Webdriver how to look to scripts links?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm have some code here. Just want to find some script on the page, and check that's script name with my list of them. Look at the code, please.

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
class TestFirefox(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    def test_python(self):
            driver = self.driver
            link = "https://www.python.org/"
            driver.get(link)
            find_js = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('script')
            find_js_xpath = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/head/script[2]')
            print(find_js)
            print(find_js_xpath)
    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

What it shows to me? Some weird thing.

```
C:\test>python new3
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="56d22575-664f-4619-bcc4-15dc7dddbb0c", element="{eaf6f627-4635-49bc-899a-5637124406a2}")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="56d22575-664f-4619-bcc4-15dc7dddbb0c", element="{a92f1e09-4270-4c72-a93e-24ce7ef70868}")>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 8.397s
```

But I want see something from string below:

```
<script src="/static/js/libs/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Something like a `src="thatgoddamnlink"` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see printed is the *string representation of a [`WebElement` class](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) instance*.

If you want to see the `src` attribute value, call `get_attribute()`:

```
print(find_js.get_attribute("src"))
```

If you want to see the text of the element:

```
print(find_js.text)
```